# Access denied for user 'myuser'@10.% to database 'mydb' - Mysql Import SQL Script

Tags: mysql, backup, mysqldump

I have a database that I am trying to recreate at my web host. I used mysqldump to create a sql script. My web hosting company, IPage, has a hosted mysqladmin site where I am supposed to be able to import my script. When I run the script I get this error:

**#1044 - Access denied for user 'myuser'@'10.%' to database 'mydatabase'**

This user has full access to the database. Do I need to make some edits to my SQL script to get this working? Or is this a problem at my hosting site?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message itself looks like an authentication issue.

Here is what you should do: If you can connect to the hosting company's mysql database from the mysql client, run this command:

```
SELECT USER() RequestedUserLogin,CURRENT_USER() AllowedUserLogin;
```

What will these functions give you ?

- [USER()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_user) reports how you attempted to authenticate in MySQL
- [CURRENT_USER()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_current-user) reports how you were allowed to authenticate in MySQL

It's the second function you need to be concerned with because it says you have the same user permissons as `AllowedUserLogin`.

@Abdul's answer reveals a deeper issue: You created the mysqldump which has the command to create the database. When you mysqldump with the --databases option, the `create database mydb;` is inserted before the `use mydb;`. You can hide the `create database mydb;` by doing

```
mysqldump -u... -p... --no-data --databases mydb > mydbschema.sql
mysqldump -u... -p... --no-create-info      mydb > mydbdata.sql
```

This will place the database and table creation statements in `mydbschema.sql` while the bulk INSERTs are placed in `mydbdata.sql`.

If you cannot run `mydbschema.sql` then have the hosting company create the database for you. You could also use whatever DB tools they have setup for you to create the database yourself.

You could then load the data using

```
mysql -umyuser -pmypassword -h(IP-of-DBServer) -Dmydb < mydbdata.sql
```

I also noticed the user mysql was expecting 'myuser'@'10.%' as the user to authenticate. You might need 'myuser'@'IP-of-DBServer' defined on the database mydb with this:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mydb.* TO 'myuser'@'IP-of-DBServer';
```

Give it a Try !!!

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion your sql file contains the `create database mydatabase;` statement

And `myuser` have not the permissions to create that database.So generate the dump without the create database statement.

Or comment it out in your sql file  use  `--` for commenting a line in sql file.

Comment: @Nick : if you need help regarding the `mysqldump` let me know.